# BFS path finding cannot find it's path

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, breadth-first-search, path-finding

Trying to implement Breadth First Search in Unity. I feel I have set up the Grid and logic for the algorithm correctly but for some reason I am getting an "KeyNotFoundException" inside the `VisualizePath` function. The end path should have been added to the Dictionary but it's failing to find it which I assume means, It did not get added? I am not sure if this is causing the problem. Would appreciate any insight into where I might be going wrong.

Added my Grid to Pastebin since this is part of the path finding.
[Grid.cs](https://pastebin.com/YPmmy5i1)

BFS.cs

```
public GridGenerator GridData;

Queue<Node> queue;
HashSet<Vector3> visited;

Dictionary<Node, Node> nodeParents;

private void Start()
{
    queue = new Queue<Node>();
    visited = new HashSet<Vector3>();
    nodeParents = new Dictionary<Node, Node>();
}

public void Search()
{
    ClearData();

    queue.Enqueue(GridData.StartPosition);
    visited.Add(GridData.StartPosition.Position);

    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        var currentNode = queue.Dequeue();

        if(currentNode.Position == GridData.EndPosition.Position)
        {
            Debug.Log("Made it to the destination");
            GridData.VisualizePath(nodeParents);
            return;
        }

        var neighbours = GridData.GetNeighbours(nodeParents);
        foreach (var neighbour in neighbours)
        {
            if(!visited.Contains(neighbour.Position))
            {
                queue.Enqueue(neighbour);
                visited.Add(neighbour.Position);
                nodeParents[neighbour] = currentNode;
            }
        }
    }

    Debug.Log("Could not find a path to the destination");
}

private void ClearData()
{
    queue.Clear();
    visited.Clear();
    cellParents.Clear();
}
```

VisualizePath function from Grid class

```
public void VisualizePath(Dictionary<Node, Node> cellParents)
{
    var path = new List<Node>();
    var current = cellParents[EndPosition];
    path.Add(EndPosition);

    while(current.Position != StartPosition.Position)
    {
        path.Add(current);
        current = cellParents[current];
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < path.Count; i++)
    {
        var pathCellPosition = path[i];
        pathCellPosition.Position = new Vector3(pathCellPosition.Position.x, PathPrefab.transform.position.y, pathCellPosition.Position.z);

        Instantiate(PathPrefab, pathCellPosition.Position, Quaternion.identity, PathCells);
    }

    MovePlayer(path);
}
```

Node class

```
public enum CellType
{ 
    Water,
    Land,
    Sand
}

public class Node
{
    public Vector3 Position { get; set; }
    public CellType CellType { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
    public Node parent { get; set; }

public Node(Vector3 position, CellType cellType, int cost)
{
    Position = position;
    CellType = cellType;
    Cost = cost;
}
```

}

Comment: I would start by not comparing the position but more likely finding which is the end node and then run the comparison on the node. Now about the code, I don't understand the point of a dictionary, path algorithms should return a list of points/nodes.

Comment: @fafase The dictionary is used to keep track of the node and it's parent. The path is then built using the dictionary in the `VisualizePath` function.

Comment: The BFS should return a list of node, the order of the list should already reflects the parent/child relation since you would push to the list in order. Also, by nature a node contains its parent and children, else it is a point and not a node.

Comment: @fafase Ahh okay. Think I am slightly confused still about this. How might you recommend changing the Search. I updated the post to add my `Node` class to which I have now added a Node parent.